# Why doesn't str.endswith allow the "suffix" parameter to be a list?

Tags: python, string, typeerror

I see the `str.endswith` method allows the `suffix` param to be a ***tuple of strings***:

```
Docstring:
S.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]]) -> bool
Return True if S ends with the specified suffix, False otherwise.
With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
suffix can also be a tuple of strings to try.
```

so I was guessing it also accepts a ***list of strings*** or some other ***iterables***, but when I tried that, passing a list raises error:

```
In [300]: s='aaa'
In [301]: s.endswith(('a', 'b'))
Out[301]: True
In [302]: s.endswith(['a', 'b'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-302-d70816089fed> in <module>()
----> 1 s.endswith(['a', 'b'])
TypeError: endswith first arg must be str, unicode, or tuple, not list
```

So why it accepts only a ***tuple of strings***?

Comment: Well, it can't be *any* iterable (with the same meaning), as strings are iterable and are handled differently.

Comment: @delnan, ok, not *any*, but isn't tuples similar to lists when pass as parameters?

Comment: @zhangxaochen Tuples are immutable, they cannot be modified when passed to a function. But a list is mutable.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thx I already know that, but as `endswith` is not intending to modify that param, does that matter if pass a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API simply echoes `isinstance()` and `except (Exception1, Exception2)` syntax, which both only accept tuples as well.

See the [original feature request](http://bugs.python.org/issue1491485):

> In the same way that exceptions can have a tuple of types specified and isinstance can take a tuple of types, str.startswith and endswith could take a tuple of possible prefixes/suffixes.

There is no reason the code couldn't support arbitrary, non-string iterables (yielding strings). You could file a feature request in the [Python issue tracker](http://bugs.python.org/) for that if you feel strongly about this. However, know that Guido van Rossum has already [stated that they are not interested in changing this](https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-ideas/24539/):

> All in all I hope you will give up your push for this feature. It just
>   doesn't seem all that important, and you really just move the
>   inconsistency to a different place (special-casing strings instead of
>   tuples).

Comment: so is there any reason that `isinstance` accepts a tuple but not a list? is it also historical or else?

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment. I looked through the Python source history, and `isinstance` has only supported tuples for eons. I don't see a current reason not to support a list as well. I'd say it is historical.

Answer (score 3):

Probably `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` accept only `tuples` and don't accept `lists` because of the historical reasons: [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) works the same way since December 21, 2001 (the day Python 2.2 was released).

Here's the excerpt from the startswith/endwith [feature request](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2006-June/033651.html):

> In the same way that *exceptions* can have a *tuple of types* specified
>   and *isinstance* can take a *tuple* of  types, str.startswith and endswith
>   could take a *tuple* of possible prefixes/suffixes.

Answer (score 3):

There was [a recent push for `str.startswith()` supporting other non-string iterables beside `tuple`s](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-ideas/24539/).

Guido was against it though.